# validation in wmp files

Tags: asp.net

i have windows media player in my application.i want to allow only the supported files for the player, to upload.i want to play photos,videos and audio files with windows media player.how can i do this?how can i validate the uploading files?
please help me

Comment: which of video file you want to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Regular Expression

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rexpImageE" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="fupImageE" ErrorMessage="Only .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .tiff, .mp3, .dat"
        ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Bb][Mm][Pp])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])|.*\.([tT][iI][iI][fF])|.*\.([mM][pP][3])|.*\.([dD][aA][tT])$)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and you can add more extensions to add something like before $ sign |.*.([dD][aA][tT])

Comment: which types of video files will support?

Comment: there is a eror

(.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Bb][Mm][Pp])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])|.*\.([tT][iI][iI][fF]|.*\.([mM][pP][3]|.*\.([dD][aA][tT])$) is not a valid regular expression.